# I am trying to use javax.swing.timer . The code in actionperformed method is not running. May be the timer is not starting. What is the fault?

Tags: java, timer

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimeController {

    public static void main(String arg[]){

        TimeController m = new TimeController();
        System.out.println("starting");
        m.start();

    }

    Timer timer = new Timer (1000, new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Running");
        }   
    });

    public void start(){
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you running it? I copied it to a file, compiled it, and ran it from the command line and it worked as expected, printing "starting" then printing "Running" once a second. (On edit) Interesting, I initially tried it with Java 1.6 and it works, but after reading Stefan's answer below (and saying "D'oh!" :-) ), I tried it on Java 1.7, where it works as you say. I think the 1.7 behavior is correct, but it's curious the Timer keeps it running in 1.6.

Comment: Your example won't run because the main thread will exit before the API has a chance to established the event dispatch thread, even if the EDT was established, it's unlikely to run because when main exits, without any other open dreamed the EDT will terminate anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no fault at all.

- The `Timer` starts its task in the background
- Your application terminates before the first execution of the Timers method takes place.

For testing you could add

```
try {
  Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch(Exception e){
  // Add exception handling
}
```

right after `m.start();

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the `Timer` needs to fire at least once to prevent the program from termination. After it fires once, it does hold the program running, even after the `main` method terminates.

Probably the bug got unnoticed as this is a rather unusual work flow. Delay the termination of the main thread as proposed by @StefanFreitag.